# Cookies and render for an angular js app using Phantomjs and python

Tags: angularjs, python-3.x, cookies, selenium-webdriver, phantomjs

I have an object that can call a web page fine, even with `add_cookie`. However, I want to render a site that is making heavy use of angularjs. For some reason I seem to be unable to set the correct cookies, which I have pulled from a live session. So I am uncertain how much of this is cookie-foo that I'm getting wrong, and how much is angular-js-foo that needs to happen that I'm missing. If people have input here that would be great, but even comments pointing me to where to go ingest would be helpful because I'm not getting far on my own. I've scrubbed the values following. Even some pointers on how to debug this. My goal is to render the `div`s on the page.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

class WebPage():

    def __init__(self):

        dcap = dict(DesiredCapabilities.PHANTOMJS)
        dcap["phantomjs.page.settings.userAgent"] = (
            "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/53 "
            "(KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/15.0.87"
        )
        self.driver = webdriver.PhantomJS(desired_capabilities=dcap, service_args=['--ignore-ssl-errors=true', '--ssl-protocol=any'])
        self.driver.set_window_size(1024, 768)

    def get_page(self):
        url = "http://proadvisor.intuit.com/search/index-standalone.html?v2#/search-result?location=60613&distance=500"
        self.driver.get(url)
        cookie = {'aam_aud': 'a_value', 'ttax': 0}
        self.driver.add_cookie(cookie)
        page = BeautifulSoup(self.driver.page_source, "lxml")
        page.find_all("div")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    wp = WebPage()
    wp.get_page()
```

and just now getting:

> selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Error Message => 'Can only set Cookies for the current domain'
>    caused by Request => {"headers":{"Accept":"application/json","Accept-Encoding":"identity","Connection":"close","Content-Length":"104","Content-Type":"application/json;charset=UTF-8","Host":"127.0.0.1:34940","User-Agent":"Python-urllib/3.3"},"httpVersion":"1.1","method":"POST","post":"{\"cookie\": {\"aam_aud\": \"a_value\", \"ttax\": 0}, \"sessionId\": \"A-hash\"}","url":"/cookie","urlParsed":{"anchor":"","query":"","file":"cookie","directory":"/","path":"/cookie","relative":"/cookie","port":"","host":"","password":"","user":"","userInfo":"","authority":"","protocol":"","source":"/cookie","queryKey":{},"chunks":["cookie"]},"urlOriginal":"/session/a_hash/cookie"}

Answer (score 1):

You have to add domain to your cookie.

Try something like this:

```
cookie = {'aam_aud': 'a_value', 'ttax': 0, 'domain' : http://proadvisor.intuit.com}
```

You might have to play with it a bit for your base URL, but I think that should work.  You have to tell the cookie on what websites you want to use that cookie on.